# python read and write to file adds unexpected chars when script interrupted

Tags: python-3.x, text-files, read-write

Here’s my problem, I have a script that has many steps, basically it opens a file, reads it and after reading it it writes back into the file. All is good when the script completes. Problems occur when there is an exception of sorts or the script is interrupted. 
I open the file in ‘r+’ mode because if I open it in ‘w’ mode, the file becomes blank right away, and if the script is interrupted, it stays blank, while I want it to keep the previous value. 
Below is an example, but not the exact script I am running
If the script is interrupted (or exception occurs, even if it is handled), the value inside the test.txt will be “myVar=13e” or “myVar=13ne”. Not always, but often.
Why does it happen and how to avoid it?

```
import time
from test import myVar
file_path = "./test.py"
with open(file_path, 'r+', encoding=‘utf-8’) as f:
    # read the file content which is for example “myVar=11”
    # do calculations with myVar
    #str_to_oc = "myVar="+str(row[0]) #row[0] is fetched from database, it’s ID of the record. It’s an integer
    str_to_oc = “myVar=“+str(13) # I hardcoded the 13 value here instead of the database row[0]
    time.sleep(3) #just adding a delay so you can interrupt easily
    # write back a string “myVar=13” which is he new value of 13
    f.write(str_to_oc)
```

**Edited the code sample to make it easy to test**

One more point: things like this can happen due to the default encoding of the system on which the script is running. The solution would be to always specify the encoding explicitly on both read and write with something like `encoding='utf_8'`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are seeing a buffering effect.

You can reduce the effect by tacking on a [flush](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.BufferedWriter.flush) call:

```
    f.write(str_to_oc)
    f.flush()
```

A CTRL/C arrives asynchronously, so this won't fix it entirely.
Also, if you choose to insert / delete,
so that individual records and the overall file size change,
you will be unhappy with how old + new records are misaligned.

Behind the scenes, an `io.BufferedWriter` is occasionally
requesting a raw [write](https://docs.python.org/3/library/io.html#io.RawIOBase.write),
which turns into an OS-level [syscall](https://linux.die.net/man/2/write).
You say that CTRL/C or fatal stack trace causes the program to terminate early.
In that case the whole python interpreter process exits,
causing implicit [`close()`](https://linux.die.net/man/2/close),
which can lead to a combination of old + new bytes being read from your file.
Note that a multibyte UTF8 code point can span disk blocks,
which may lead to unhappiness.

Given the observed reliability of your program,
it sounds like you would be well served to leave the original untouched
until processing successfully completes:

```
tmp_path = file_path + '.tmp'
with open(file_path) as fin:
    with open(tmp_path, 'w') as fout:
        for line in fin:
            # (do stuff, compute output)
            fout.write(out_line + '\n')

os.rename(tmp_path, file_path)  # atomic operation, all-or-nothing
```

Comment: Thanks for this explanation! Actually the interruption was caused by a lost database connection, not a Cntrl-C. But still, I have the code in the function and call the function with “try:” and “except:” inside a while loop. This way the script restarts itself. You answer sheds light on why those seemingly random values of “e” and “ne” appear.

Answer (score 0):

A very naive solution would simply be to read the file into memory, assuming it's as short as your example implies, and rewrite the file contents in the event of an exception. You could also use a temporary file to avoid clobbering the original, and then only write in the event of success.

Comment: Good ideas regarding how to avoid it. What about why it happens?

Comment: Filesystems are complicated beasts. IO to filesystems from high level languages even moreso. My best guess is "something going down the wrong pipe," as it were, probably some implementation level stuff in Python itself. But this is speculation.

Answer (score 0):

Just for anyone interested, I did a bit of a hack-ish thing and appended the comment to the string I write to the file..

```
str_to_oc = “myVar=“+str(13)+”#”
```